# Python - Help on genetic algorithm error

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic

I've been trying to create a genetic algorithm in python but i either get:

```
<bound method Environment.bestsol of <__main__.Environment instance
at 0x10a5d4ab8>>
```

or it doesn't print. I've tried to rearrange the functions, and call the function directly, but it still does not output anything. I seem to be having trouble with something relating to the function `bestsol()`.

```
import random
import sys
from operator import attrgetter
input = 1
target = 5.5
class Individual:
    def __init__(self, constant):
        self.fitness = getfitness()
        self.constant = constant
    def getconstant():
        return self.constant
    def getresult():
        return self.constant * input
    def getfitness():
        return 10 - abs(target - self.getresult())
    def mutate():
        if(random.random() > .05):
            self.constant + random.random()
    def offspring(partner):
        return Individual(((self.getconstant() + partner.getconstant())/2))
class Generation(list):
    def __init__(self, gensize, fitsize, startinglist=[]):
        self.extend(startinglist)
        self.bredoff = []
        self.gensize = gensize
        self.fitsize = fitsize
        self.make()
    def make():
        self = [Individual(random.randint(-10,10)) for x in xrange((self.gensize-len(self)))]

    def getfittest():
        return heapq.nlargest(self.fitsize,self,key=attrgetter('fitness'))
    def getbredoffspring():
        for i in self.getfittest():
            bredoff.append(i.offspring(self.getfittest[random.randint(0,len(self.getfittest()))]))
        return bredoff
class Environment():
    def __init__(self, maxgens):
        self.l = []
        self.b = []
        self.maxgens = maxgens
    def create():
        l = Generation(100,20)
        for i in maxgens:
            b = l.getbredoffspring()
            l = Generation(100,20,b)
    def bestsol():
        print("e")
        print max(l,key=attrgetter('fitness')).fitness()

def main():
    sol = Environment(2)
    print sol.bestsol
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With me being new to python i can't understand even after searching the internet as best i could. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @alfasin beat me to it. To expand upon his first point a little.. when you use a method without the parentheses, you get your `bound method ..` 'error.' It's not actually an error though. It's just telling you it's an instance of that method stored in memory location 0x10a5d4ab8. When you add the `()`s, your (bound) method will carry out the code within

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bestsol` is a class method, so when you call it you should use brackets: `sol.bestsol()` (otherwise, you're print the method object: `<bound method Environment.bestsol ...`).

Second, when you define a class-method you should declare `self` as an argument:

```
def bestsol(self):  # <-- here
    print("e")
    print max(l,key=attrgetter('fitness')).fitness()
```

Third, when you declare a class that doesn't extend any other class - you should either declare that it inherits from `object` (old way):

```
class Environment(object):
```

or, no brackets at all (new way)

```
class Environment:
```

Forth, when you create a class member, say `l` (you *really* should use better names btw), whenever you want to use it you should use the `self` annotation: `self.l`. If you'll use `l` it will create a local variable inside the method - and that's probably *not* what you intended.

There are other problems with the code but I'll let you struggle with it a bit so you can learn :)